# Difference in hours between two dates and times by javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datetime

I have three input fields of type text in my html file.

1. First input field is called OLD DATE & TIME.
2. Second input field is called NEW DATE & TIME.
3. Third Input field is called DIFFERENCE IN HOURS.

What I would like is:

- if a user enters the first input field (old date & time) and then enters the second input field (new date & time), the third input field must show the difference in hours automatically **only** after the second input field filled with date & time and **loose focus (onBlur)**.
- The third input (difference in hours) will not give answer if the second input (new date & time) or the first input (old date & time) is empty.

And I would be very delighted to have a **datetime picker** on the first and second input.

Here is the code:

```
<label>OLD DATE & TIME: </label>
<input id="old" type="datetime-local" name="old" />
<p>
    <label>NEW DATE & TIME: </label>
    <input id="new" type="datetime-local" name="new" onBlur="document.getElementById('total').value = (new Date(this.value) - new Date(old.value))/(1000*60*60)" />
<p>
<label>DIFFERENCE IN HOURS :</label>
<br>
<input id="total" type="text" name="total" onChange="changeDate()" />
```

i know firefox and internet explores does not support input type =datetime-local, so i want to use input type text but it always give me NaN.

Comment: what do you have so far?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please have a read through [Stack Overflow help on asking](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) to see what kinds of questions are on topic. In particular, we would be happy to help you solve your problem, but if you need code written for you (without effort from you), we suggest you hire a programmer instead.

Comment: This reads like a feature brief, not an actual question. We are not your personal dev team.

Comment: [<input> elements with type="datetime-local" are not supported in Internet Explorer or Firefox](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_datetime-local.asp) might help you

Comment: The code works fine, now i know that i was entering date in this format dd-mm-yyyy when it needs to be in dd/mm/yyyy format for date

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use plain javascript then you can do calculations in this way..

```
    var fromDate = parseInt(new Date(oldDate).getTime()/1000); 
    var toDate = parseInt(new Date(newDate).getTime()/1000);
    var timeDiff = (toDate - fromDate)/3600;  // will give difference in hrs
```

Comment: It works like awesome

Answer (score 2):

Please use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/). this also can changing formate of date and time.

```
var now  = "04/09/2013 15:00:00";
var then = "04/09/2013 14:20:30";

moment.utc(moment(now, "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss").diff(moment(then, "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss"))).format("HH:mm:ss")
```

Comment: @VonMicky: Again, as others have remarked: if you can't correct your code yourself after we've shown you where to look and/or how to fix it, you should hire a programmer. Give it a try, let us see what you came up with and we'll point out any problems or answer any (**concrete!**) questions you may have.

Answer (score 0):

The `Date` object has a `getTime()` method which returns the number of milliseconds since midnight Jan 1, 1970. You could create a `Date` object for the two dates you're dealing with, call `getTime()` on each, subtract the difference and convert the result to hours.

Comment: Replace
(new Date(this.value) - new Date(old.value))/(1000*60*60)
with
(new Date(this.value).getTime() - new Date(old.value).getTime())/(1000*60*60)

Comment: get Time() did the job nicely.